# Tag/Branch Creation

Tags: svn, repository

Suppose we have created empty SVN repository without specifying trunk/branch/tag folder and after multiple svn commits if we wish to create a tag/ branch. Is that possible? Is there any way to achieve that?

Comment: The names `trunk`, `branch` and `tag` have no special meaning to Subversion. You can create a `tag` folder just the same as any other folder.

Answer (score 1):

A `tag` or `branch` is nothing more than the result of an [`svn copy`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.ref.svn.c.copy.html) command. Those folders are typically made out of convention, and if you wanted to change the structure of your repository at any time to adopt said convention, you can.

For example, let's say you made an empty repository with the structure:

```
MyRepo
|_ Folder1
|_ Folder2
```

With `Folder1` and `Folder2` containing work items. You can always `svn checkout` the root of the repository, create a new folder called `trunk` and then perform an `svn move` of Folder1 and Folder2 underneath the `trunk` and the commit the changes. Then you can make a branch/tag of the trunk by performing an `svn copy` on the trunk as necessary.

--

Additionally, you can always just make copies of whatever folders under the repository as necessary:

`svn copy /path/to/MyRepo/Checkout url/to/MyRepo/MyBranch`

Comment: Thank you Chris for giving answer. Can the history be restored if we create trunk and work on that? Like the way which you have explained ?

Comment: svn copy and svn move command preserve history as SVN knows about their origin. In TortoiseSVN disable "Stop on Copy/Rename" in the log dialog to see also common history.

Comment: Thank you so much for reply. I will try the solution you shared.